# Set selection options depending on another select element's value in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, json, angularjs

I nearly struggled as much naming this question as I am with the actual problem! I have two selects:

Select 1:

```
<select ng-change="bankSelected()" ng-model="user.bankName">
    <option selected value="">Select</option>
    <option ng-repeat="bank in banks" value="{{bank.name}}">{{bank.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Select 2:

```
<select ng-model="user.branch">
    <option selected value="">Select</option>
    <option ng-repeat="// what to do??"></option>
</select>
```

The 'bankSelected()' function in my controller:

```
$scope.bankSelected = function () {
    console.log('Bank selected: ' + $scope.user.bankName);
}
```

I have a JSON file that I import all the bank objects from, here's an example:

```
{
    "banks" : [
        {
            "name" : "Bank A",
            "branches" : [
                {
                    "name" : "Branch 1",
                    "code" : "1"
                },
                {
                    "name" : "Branch 2",
                    "code" : "2"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name" : "Bank B",
            "branches" : [
                {
                    "name" : "Branch 3",
                    "code" : "3"
                },
                {
                    "name" : "Branch 4",
                    "code" : "4"
                },
                {
                    "name" : "Branch 5",
                    "code" : "5"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The JSON that I'm actually using though is about 1000 lines long. So my problem, is that if the user selects `'Bank A'` in the first select box, I want the second select box to display `'Branch 1'` and `'Branch 2'`. Likewise if the user selects `'Bank B'`, I want to display `'Branch 3'`, `'Branch 4'`, and `'Branch 5'`. If the user has not selected anything in the first select (e.g. no Bank selected), then the second select (branches) shouldn't contain anything. I'm sure you understand what I'm getting at?

How can I make this happen in AngularJS?

Comment: can you create a plunk ?

Comment: Why not `ng-repeat="branch in branches`? No one prevents you from updating `branches` in `bankSelected()`.

Comment: @zeroflagL does that mean that in bankSelected() I have to have a long switch statement updating the branches list depending on what bank was selected?

Comment: Rather something like `getBranches` from K.Torress's answer. But updating `branches` doesn't have an impact on performance, contrary to calling `getBranches` on each digest cycle.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

bank `ng-repeat`

```
<select ng-model="user.bankName">
    <option selected value="">Select</option>
    <option ng-repeat="bank in banks" value="{{bank.name}}">{{bank.name}}</option>
</select>
```

branch `ng-repeat`

```
<select ng-model="user.branch" ng-show="user.bankName">
    <option selected value="">Select</option>
    <option ng-repeat="branch in getBranches(user.bankName)" value="{{branch.code}}">{{ branch.name }}</option>
</select>
```

source of the branch repeat is assign to `getBranches()` function in  the scope and here we pass the bank name which selected before.

in that function

```
$scope.getBranches = function(selectedBank) {

    // get the selected bank object from the banks array
    var filteredBank = $filter('filter')($scope.banks, selectedBank);

    // return the branches of the selected bank
    return filteredBank[0].branches;
};
```

don't forget to inject the `$filter` service as below

```
app.controller('CtrlName', function($scope, $filter) {...
```

here is the [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/1OeqVEazyDtttfvDlJQh?p=info)

---

If you can change your select to something like below it will be more cleaner :)

this will select the whole object of the selected option.

```
<select ng-model="user.bankName" ng-options="bank.name for bank in banks">
</select>
```

here we can use selected bank object to get the branches as `user.bankName.branches`.

```
<select ng-model="user.branch" ng-if="user.bankName" ng-options="branch.code as branch.name for branch in user.bankName.branches">
</select>
```

so we can get rid of the `getBranches()`.

here is the [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/Cw2qsvPpgEqaFDZLk6yQ?p=preview)